# run a script in multiple folders in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, directory

I have a folder Cabo_Verde, and inside this folder I have several folders (001 to 300) with several files each, like this:

Filename: Cabo_verde

```
     001
     2008.001.00.00.CVBR1.LHZ.SAC
     2008.001.00.00.CVBR2.LHZ.SAC
     ...

     002
     2008.002.00.00.CVBR1.LHZ.SAC
     2008.002.00.00.CVBR2.LHZ.SAC
     ...
```

I want to run a script in each folder and this is what I did:

```
for dir in `ls $Cabo_verde`;
do
   for subdir in `ls $Cabo_Verde/$dir`;
   do
      $(for file in *SAC; do
sac <<EOF
echo on
read $file
chnhdr KCMPNM LHZ
write over
quit
EOF
done)
done;
done
```

In the end I got

```
ls:cannot access /001: No such file or directory
ls:cannot access /002: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: You are showing what you did but not what you got. Please include the result and a description of the issue.

Comment: `$Cabo_Verde` is not `$Cabo_verde`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a reliability aid, i suggest writing and running all your scripts with `set -u`, your parameter name typo would be immediately obvious.

you say you want to run a script in each directory, but is it actually true?  anyway...

you can either nest two loops like this:

```
for d in Cabo_Verde/*/; do
  cd $d
  for f in *.SAC; do
    sac ... $f
  done
done
```

or you can do it with a single loop like this:

```
for f in Cabo_Verde/*/*.SAC; do
  cd ${f%/*}
  sac ... $f
done
```

of course, you don't need any loops at all:

```
find Cabo_Verde -name \*.SAC -execdir tool
```

where `tool` is a script containing `sac ... < $1`